# 301 redirect .HTACCESS - Remove Query String

Tags: string, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a 404 page being found by analytics. I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax for redirecting the link below via .htaccess.  Can anyone offer a solution? Thank you very much.

`http://www.mywebsite.com/product-categories?format=feed&type=atom`

I tried this and plenty of others without success.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=feed&type=atom$
RewriteRule ^product-categories/$ http://www.mywebsite.com/product-categories/?  [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have condition reverse in your `RewriteRule`. Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=feed&type=atom$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product-categories/?$ /product-categories/? [NC,NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: You're awesome anubhava!  That was it.  Also, my .htaccess file has some RewriteCond for security and I had to put the code above the security RewriteCond and below the RewriteEngine On. When I had it further down in the file it didn't work, but once it was placed hire in the file it worked like a charm.  Thanks again :)

Comment: That is great, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark on top left of my answer.